# Django AttributeError: type object 'Post' has no attribute 'object'

Tags: django, python-3.x, attributes

I have been working on my first website. I have this Error that i don't understand.I have looked over the code and can't see where i went wrong.

[image: Look at error.]

All the code is [here](https://github.com/jay1022/Mysite/tree/master/mysite/blog)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If my answer helped you then mark it as accepted please. Its a good practice in StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

Is that a typo?

Change `urls.py` to this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(
    queryset=Post.objects.order_by('-date')[:25],
    template_name="blog/blog.html")),
]
```

Notice I have appended an `s` in `Post.object`. Also removed `all()` (it's reduntant).